# SimpleModal in jQuery

Tags: jquery, redirect, simplemodal

I am using SimpleModal in jQuery, and I use Ajax for displaying radio buttons.
It should list the radio button and values. After the radio button click,
the page is to be redirected to page2.

When I tested it on localhost, everything was fine. But it doesn't redirect
the page on the web server.

Any change I should make?

My code:

```
..............
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#resp').modal({
            close: false,
            position: ["4%",],
            overlayId: 'confirmRespOverlay',
            containerId: 'confirmRespContainer',
            onShow: function (second) {
                second.data.find(".buttons .yes").hide();
                var resp = $("<div/>").append(data);
                var title = resp.find("#title").html(),
                message = resp.find("#message").html();
                second.data.find(".header span").html(title);
                second.data.find('.info').append(message);
                second.data.find('.yes').click(function () {
                });
            }//onShow
        }); //Resp

        $("input:radio").click(function() {
            var url="http://page2"
            window.location.replace(url);
        }); //input
    }//success
}); //ajax
```

test.php returns following

```
echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"value_\" onClick=\"showUser(this.value)\" value=".$id1.">".$val1."</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"value_\" onClick=\"showUser(this.value)\" value=".$id2.">".$val2."</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";
```

The page stopped after clicking the radio button and doesn't move to next page. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where does the showUser function come into it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using Firebug under Firefox? Maybe set a breakpoint in the "click" function to see when it gets called?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your inputs haven't been added when you are registering the events.

There are two options one  load your data into the modal before showing it (ie. bypassing your onshow method)

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'test.php', 
   cache: false, 
   success: function(data) { 
       var second = $('#resp');
       second.data.find(".buttons .yes").hide();
       var resp = $("<div/>").append(data);
       var title = resp.find("#title").html();
       message = resp.find("#message").html();
       second.data.find(".header span").html(title);
       second.data.find('.info').append(message);
       second.data.find('.yes').click(function () {
       }); // click

       $('#resp').modal({
          close:false,
          position: ["4%",],
          overlayId:'confirmRespOverlay',
          containerId:'confirmRespContainer'
        }); //Resp

       $("input:radio").click(function() {
            var url="http://page2"
            window.location.replace(url);
       }); //input 

  }//success 

}); //ajax
```

Or register your events inside the onshow method

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'test.php', 
   cache: false, 
   success: function(data) { 

       $('#resp').modal({
          close:false,
          position: ["4%",],
          overlayId:'confirmRespOverlay',
          containerId:'confirmRespContainer', 
          onShow: function (second) { 
                    second.data.find(".buttons .yes").hide();
                    var resp = $("<div/>").append(data);
                    var title = resp.find("#title").html();
                    message = resp.find("#message").html();
                    second.data.find(".header span").html(title);
                    second.data.find('.info').append(message);
                    second.data.find('.yes').click(function () {
                     });

                    $("input:radio").click(function() {
                      var url="http://page2"
                      window.location.replace(url);
                    }); //input 
          }//onShow

        }); //Resp

  }//success 

}); //ajax
```